# Errors occured when doing cmake in ubuntu

Tags: cmake

[image: error]

```
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
Git commit: v0.9.1-21-gcabdedb, Git version: 0.9.1
PolarSSL not found
Tomcrypt found
-- checking for module 'libnl-tiny'
--   package 'libnl-tiny' not found
-- checking for module 'libnl-genl-3.0'
--   package 'libnl-genl-3.0' not found
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:283 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:337 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  src-plugins/generic/nl80211_listener/CMakeLists.txt:7 (pkg_check_modules)
```

Ubuntu version 14.04.02, have updates on.

I can't seem to build it successfully, any help is appreciated.

Comment: If possible, replace the screenshot with the copy-pasted command line output. Only then the question can be found by other users with the same problem.

Comment: Which git repository?

Comment: http://olsr.org/git/oonf.git @A.B.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install the development libraries:

- To solve this: `-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE)`, execute:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install doxygen
  ```
- To solve this: `PolarSSL not found`, execute:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libpolarssl-dev
  ```
- To solve this: `--   package 'libnl-tiny' not found` and `--   package 'libnl-genl-3.0' not found`, execute:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libnl-utils
  ```

After that, clean the source folder:

```
cd ~/oomf
make clean
```

And start `cmake`  again:

```
cd build
cmake ..
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a couple of missing dependencies (Doxygen, PolarSSL, libnl-tiny, libnl-genl-3.0).

Before running `cmake` you should install required dependencies and/or *configure* the build accordingly to the dependencies available on your system. E.g., it might be possible to build without Doxygen, but other packages might be required.

Comment: I have installed the apt-get-install libpolarssl-dev package, have successfully installed all packages that you've said, can't seem to find the pollarssl and libnl tiny tho.